# Woocommerc: How to allow only one free item per account

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am setting up a WooCommerce store with three free virtual items (users can buy/create a post that lasts for 30 days).

How can I prevent users from retaining more than 1 free item at a time (e.g., the user can only have one active free item at a time), regardless of what item is it. Any help is appreciated :)

For more details, I am using WooCommerce in conjunction with WP Job Manager

My site: https://www.wgeil.de

Comment: _"the user can only have one **active** free item at a time"_ what does active stands for? product status `publish`?

Comment: Hey. The way I have my store set up, a user can "buy" a listing that is active for 30 days. That is, once 30 days have passed, the listing is archived and no longer displayed on my page. What I would like is for users to only be able to have 1 ACTIVE post at a time. So if a user tries to "purchase" another free listing and they already have an active post that is a free product, they will be denied. Does this clarify?

Comment: What is the free product? You mention a user can buy/create a post that last 30 days... doesn't sound free. Are you bundling a free item when they purchase a post? How are you handling the free item? Either way you could check if they have purchased the free item, even if it's free it's still considered a purchase. If they have purchased it hide the product or remove it from their cart if they try to purchase again. I have a plugin that does this, it limits a customer from purchasing a product more than once. http://www.pnw-design.com/product/woocommerce-limit-one-product-purchase-plugin/

Comment: The free product is (supposed) to be the ability to post for 30 days. There will also be a premium option where the post will stay active longer and be featured on the site. But I want to limit users to only one free post at a time, so that, if they want more than one post, they must purchase additional posts or a premium post. Does this make sense? I will look at your plugin!